# Function: fill the string to get a length

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to create a function that recives 3 parameters, a string a number and a char.
If the len(string) is not the same as the number given, I want to fulfill the string with the given char.
I tried doin' this, but didn't work. Where do I miss?

```
def expand(text, length, char):
new_text = ""
if length <= len(text):
    print(text)
else:
    diff = length - len(text)
    if diff % 2 == 0:
        len(new_text) == length
        new_text = char + text + char
    else:
        len(new_text) == length
        new_text = char + text + char
    new_text = char + text
print(new_text)
```

I mean how could I create a condition that helps me to add as many "char" I need but in the same time checks if len(text) is the same with the number given? If you could explain me where should I look and how do I have to think about the problem, it would be awesome. I just want to understand the way, not just to have the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach where multiplying a char by a number will give you a string of that length. eg. `'a' * 3 = 'aaa'`

```py
def expand(text, length, char):
    new_text = ""
    if length <= len(text):
        new_text = text
    else:
        diff = length - len(text)
        if diff % 2 == 0:
            new_text = char*int(diff/2) + text + char*int(diff/2)
            # length of text is automatically updated
        else:
            new_text = char*int((diff-1)/2) + text + char*int((diff-1)/2)
            new_text = char + new_text 
    print(new_text)
    return new_text
```

Comment: So at the "new_text" i specify what i want to get at the final, but if i want to have the len of new_text to be the same of the length given as parameter, what could I do? I tried len(new_text) == length, but i feel like is unclear for the computer.

Comment: This length of the text is updated automatically when you add or remove characters from the string. You don't need to worry about changing it.

Comment: So is basically updated by diff = length-len(text), right?

Comment: No. When you assign a value to `new_text` it's length will be set automatically. `new_text = text` or `new_text = char*int(diff/2) + text + char*int(diff/2)`, et c. This sets the length of the text. Because `len()` is a function - it calculates the length of the string when you call the function, it doesn't just give out a length value that you need to update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while to add the character until the string reaches the desired length:

```
new_text = text
while len(text) < length:
    if len(text)%2 == 0:
       new_text = new_text + char
    else
       new_text = char + new_text
```

If you want to generate a certain number of repeating characters, you can multiply the character by a number.  e.g. "A"*3 --> "AAA"

So you could approach it like this:

```
padLeft  = (length-len(text))//2
padRight = length-len(text)-padLeft
return  char*padLeft + text + char*padRight
```

There's also the recursive approach:

```
def expand(text, length, char):
    if len(text)>=length: return text
    if len(text)%1: return expand(text+char,length,char) 
    else:           return expand(char+text,length,char)
```